# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'. What problem it can be?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I try to create Spring data jpa program without SpringBoot.
Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"springdata.repository"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"springdata.entities.service"})
@PropertySource("classpath:data.properties")

public class SpringDataConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
    basicDataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    basicDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

    return basicDataSource;
}

@Bean
public Properties hibernateProperties() {
    final Properties hibernateProp = new Properties();
    hibernateProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.H2Dialect");
    hibernateProp.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
    hibernateProp.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
    hibernateProp.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    hibernateProp.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    hibernateProp.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
    hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
    hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);

    return hibernateProp;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(final JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter,
                                                 final Properties hibernateProperties,
                                                 final DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setPackagesToScan("springdata.entities");
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
    em.afterPropertiesSet();

    return em;
}

}
```

Test class:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws SQLException {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringDataConfig.class);
    DuckService duckService = ctx.getBean(DuckService.class);
    System.out.println(duckService.findAll().size());
}


  }
```

maven dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.Alpha2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

And there are exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in springdata.SpringDataConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

I try to find decision of this proplem, and on SO was similar question, and solution was to replace javax.persistance on hibernate.javax.persistance. But in my case, I have new exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `hibernate` dialect

```
 hibernateProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
```

Comment: Did you try like that org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect ?

Comment: What should I try? I just do so: hibernateProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.H2Dialect");